# Azure ARM - SSH public key error during incremental redeployment

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

Title is not super clear, but basically, I'm getting the `Changing property 'linuxConfiguration.ssh.publicKeys' is not allowed` when redeploying an ARM template in incremental mode.

The admin user has changed the SSH key in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` since the initial deployment, which makes sense. So I went in the file, reset it to the same public key that is in the ARM template, re-ran the whole thing: Still failed.

Tried to reset the value using Azure Portal, did both a `Reset SSH public key` and `Reset configuration only`, and the template still fails.

I'm literally copying the SSH key, as it is declared in the ARM template's parameters, and applying it to the same user, and it still fails. Is there something I'm missing, or as soon as the file is changed in any way whatsoever the template becomes basically useless without a full redeployment in Complete mode ?

Thanks!

Comment: What's error do you get when you reset the ssh key in the portal?

Comment: @CharlesXu I don't get any errors from the portal itself during the reset, the ARM template deployment simply continues to fail even after the ssh key has been reset.

Answer (score 1):

As the error displayed, directly change the property 'osProfile' is not allowed. That means your VM is already created but you try to update it with a different publicKey(even you copy the same content of `authorized_keys` file), which is not supported with the ARM template. You may have a look at [this1](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/21850) and [this2](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/21749).

If you want to update the ssh public key, you can use [this az cli commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/extension?view=azure-cli-latest#az_vm_extension_set-examples):

```
az vm extension set -n VMAccessForLinux --publisher Microsoft.OSTCExtensions --version 1.4 \
    --vm-name MyVm --resource-group MyResourceGroup \
    --protected-settings '{"username":"user1", "ssh_key":"ssh_rsa ..."}'
```

Comment: That's the thing though, the template has not been changed since it was initially deployed. The only thing that changed was in the VM itself, the SSH key of the adminuser was changed. We're not trying to use the template to change the SSH key and/or revert it to its initial setting.
We ended up simply deleting the VMs and recreating them from scratch, as they were merely jumpboxes with nothing of importance. 
But this is still a weird behaviour...